# Vuetify v-data-table showing error in props.item with nested JSON

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

Here's the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined 
> at Object.fn [as items] (app.js:74266)...

Hi guys I'm working on a `Users`[Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) component and recently updated to [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) and I'm getting the Users API from a [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6) backend from this controller. Any help or suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

#### UsersController.php

public function index()
    {
        //With data from ROLES table
        $users = User::with('role:role_id,name')->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
        return response()->json($users);
    }

The `props.item.role.name` is showing properly and the add/update functionality are also working except the errors showing after I updated a user

#### Users.vue

```
<template>
 <v-data-table
   :headers="headers"
   :items="myUsers"
   :search="search"
   :loading="isLoading"
   class="elevation-1"
  >
     <v-progress-linear slot="progress" color="blue" indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
     <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td class="text-md-left pt-3">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-md-left pt-3">{{ props.item.email }}</td>
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        **<td class="text-md-left pt-3">{{ props.item.role.name }}</td>**
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        <td class="justify-content-left layout">
          <v-btn icon @click.prevent="editUser(props.item)">
             <v-icon color="blue">edit</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon @click.prevent="deleteUser(props.item)" :disabled="props.item.name === 'admin'">
             <v-icon color="pink">delete</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </td>
     </template>

     <v-alert slot="no-results" :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
        Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
     </v-alert>

     <template slot="no-data">
        <v-btn color="primary" href="/dashboard/users" >Reset</v-btn>
     </template>

 </v-data-table>
</template>
```

#### [Edited] VueDevTools view

`myUsers.role.name` has value showing **''student''** string in the v-data-table. The `props.item.role.name` is really the source of the errors which doesn't occur when I omitted it or changed it to a non-nested JSON like `props.item.role_id`.

[[VueDevTools View - JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tRJJ.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tRJJ.png)

[[VueDevTools View - Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFbtD.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFbtD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem here. There are 2 reasons why I got the error. One in the backend (Laravel) and one in the Frontend (Vue.js).

**Backend**

My User and Role has One to many relationship so by using this fixed my update/edit of roles (this alone solved my problem)

```
$user->roles()->sync(values);
```

**Frontend**

Additionally for the minor problem, the Errors exist in updating/editing the v-data-table because  I'm using

```
Object.assign({},obj);
```

which I discovered is only suited for shallow copying of objects and fail when data are updated for the deep properties inside the object. Which obviously didn't reach props.item.role.name. By using this I coped with errors

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's telling that in your `:items="myUsers"` there is no `role.name`.

So when when you try to do `{{ props.item.role.name }}` it's poping you an error.

Look in `myUsers`, when you're having the error, with [VueDevTool](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) for example, it should miss `role.name`.

Find a way to add it, or remove that line, and datatable will be ok.

Comment: Please check my VueDevTools view.

Comment: Sorry, check it again.

Comment: May be in one of your items there's no `name` or `role.name`. Can't say more than that, without CodePen

Comment: It's not simply the "It's telling that in your :items="myUsers" there is no role.name." problem. The problem is with the data not being loaded correctly. I still don't know how to get this to work so I avoid Vuetify by all mean because it table pass props and there are a lot of problem with it.